# Creating JPEG's from binary

Tags: image, image-processing, image-manipulation

If I read some binary from a stream, save it in a text file and then rename it with the .jpg extension, how come the file won't open as an image?

As a reference, I have got the source image, opened it up in notepad and compared both files - side-by-side they have exactly the same content.

Comment: opened a binary file in notepad?

Comment: yeah, not a smart thing to do?

Comment: well, a jpeg image is not a "text file"

Comment: I thought identical binary would be interpreted as identical text?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that you didn't open your text file in binary mode. Some bytes will be changed when you write data in text mode (most notably the end-of-line byte sequence) and those changes will be ignored by Notepad because it thinks everything is text. Try using [`comp`](http://ss64.com/nt/comp.html) (I think that's the right command) to compare your files rather than Notepad.

Comment: You should also be able to compare the file sizes - any difference means they're not identical. Newline substitution should change the file size.

Comment: File sizes are bang on the same - both size and size on disk

Comment: I used comp and I got "10 mismatches - ending compare".

Comment: @nick: Then you must be changing some bytes somewhere. Are you writing the JPEG in binary mode? What bytes are changing? You might need to get yourself a hex dumper to answer the second question but you should have a hex dumper on hand if you're dealing with binary files anyway.

Comment: @Mark: True but there's always the unhappy coincidence of EOL changes combined with possible `'\0'` deletions leaving the size intact. It isn't likely that they'd exactly cancel each other but it is best to check for exactly what you need rather than things that are implied by what you need to check.